# iOSでpush通知の許可を書き換える方法

Tags: swift, ios

はじめまして。

現在iOSのアプリを作成しているのですが、通知周りで躓いています。

やりたいことは下記のような感じです。

・ViewControllerのUISwitchの値が変更されたら通知許可を書き換える
ex: 許可がtrueならUISwitchをfalseにしたら許可もfalseになる

現在通知の状態を取得することはできるのですが上書きすることはできないのか悩んでいます。

iOS11からアプリの通知設定画面にもURLスキーマで飛ばせなくなったみたいなので困っています。

どうか教えてください。もうstackoverflowです。。。

他にいいやりかたがあればご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/102761

Answer (score 2):

できません。プッシュ通知を受けるかどうかはユーザーがコントロールするものなのでユーザーが拒否しているものをアプリ側で勝手に変えることはできません。それができたら許可の仕組みが意味をなさなくなってしまいます。

Comment: すみません。言葉足らずでした。こちらアプリが勝手に変えるというわけではなく、アプリに設定画面があってその設定と設定画面の許可を同期させたいという意味合いです。ですのユーザーがわざわざ設定→通知→アプリ設定画面→許可と操作しなくてもアプリから変更する方法はないかと思いました。

Comment: それができれば実質的にプログラムから許可の設定が変えられることになるので同じことです。通知（に限らずユーザーが個別に許可する類の設定は）の設定はプログラムからは操作できません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！勉強になりました！